# When is flask's app.before_first_request called when behind apache?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have some code decorated with `@app.before_first_request`

In my testing environment when debug is set to true and I run the flask web server by calling  `python my_flask_server.py` the functions decorated with `before_first_request` do not get called until I actually make a request with the browser.

However when I use Apache and mod_wsgi to serve the flask app, it appears that when I call `from my_server import app as application` the decorated functions get executed.
This is a problem because my wsgi script looks like this:

```
import my_server
from my_server import app as application
my_server.configure_stuff() # read from a conf file
application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=False)
```

Now I need the `configure_stuff()` function to execute and to set attributes on the `app` object. However because `@app.before_request` decorated functions are run immediately after `from my_server import app as application`, I get "no attribute errors."

Anyone know how to prevent flask form executing running these decorated functions until a real request has come in?

Comment: You probably don't want to call `application.run` in your wsgi script. You want to let mod_wsgi take care of running the application for you.

Comment: Does that mean I just import the application and thats it? As in my script should look like:
``import my_server; from my_server import app as application``

Comment: Yes. mod_wsgi will take care of running it for you